# Calculating goodness of fit and rmsea from factor_analyser in python

Tags: python, factor-analysis, goodness-of-fit

I am performing Confirmatory factor analysis in python using the [factor_analyzer](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/factor-analyzer/latest/factor-analyzer.pdf) module.

I have searched hi and low for a way to generate the model diagnostics such as the Root Mean Square Error of Approximation, the chi square, the CFI and Tucker-Lewis index. I'm not particularly mathematically inclined and relatively new to python but I have been able to muddle through for the most part.

I understand that the factor_analyzer module produces a lot of different objects that allow would, in-theory, allow me to carry out additional calculations and I have found [this document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.05598.pdf) which provides me with most of the formula I need. However, I do not know what to take (or calculate) to get the model diagnostics I need.

The CFA code is

```
model_dict = {"F1": factor_1,
              "F2": factor_2}# I have made these lists previously

model_spec = ModelSpecificationParser.parse_model_specification_from_dict(df[influence_scale],
                                                                           model_dict)
cfa = ConfirmatoryFactorAnalyzer(model_spec, disp=False)

cfa.fit(df[influence_scale].values)

cfa_loadings = pd.DataFrame(cfa.loadings_)
```

I have gotten no errors and the code works fine giving me clean loadings as I would have expected on each factor, however I'm really stuck on getting the additional stats I need.

If anyone can help me out I'd really really appreciate it.

Comment: I also cannot locate any documentation on this. I would like to compute CMIN, CFI, SRMR, RMSEA, etc. like in MPlus or AMOS.

Comment: Have you thought about [raising an issue on this](https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/factor_analyzer/blob/main/doc/factor_analyzer.rst)? I think this would be a very useful addition to the factor_analyzer package.

Comment: I have thought of it but honestly I'm not sure how to do it. I'm pretty new to the world of packages.

Comment: I raised an issue for you on the [Github Page](https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/factor_analyzer/issues/70)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the chisquare using scipy.stats:

`X, p = stats.chisquare(cfa_loadings)`

However, I'm also stuck on the other GFI indices.

Comment: I'd love to have time (and development skill) to add more user and student friendly functionality to this package.